# Unable to install packages with pip (SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I've been unable to download any package with `pip` and I keep getting the same error about a problem confirming the SSL certificate. I'm currently on my university's network and I also have Anaconda installed on my laptop. I'm not sure if those two factors have anything to do with this issue.

I am using `python` version `3.7.0`, `pip` version `9.0.1` and `pip3` version `10.0.1`.

When I type `pip install django` in the terminal I get this result:

```
Collecting django
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/:
     There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: 
     [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
     - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

I've read several other threads. I've tried commands such as these without success:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host \
  files.pythonhosted.org django
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5363) you should also add `pypi.python.org` to the command line as a trusted host, i.e.:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org \
            --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org django
```

Comment: pip 1.4.1 under Python 2.7 (Windows 10): "no such option --trusted-host"

Comment: @MikeC The issue I linked refers to `pip` version 10.0.1. You should upgrade your `pip` first. If you are unable to upgrade it using `pip` you may try downloading the `.whl` file from https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue  the solution worked for me is by adding three path to environment variables

```
C:\Anaconda3; 

C:\Anaconda3\Scripts; 

C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
```

I had been using python 3.7.1 with anaconda 4.8.2  on window 7. You may check for missing path environment variable and add only the missing ones.

Answer (score -1):

Open Anaconda prompt and run the following:

```
conda install -f pip

pip install pandas
```